# Android viewpager with fragmentpageradapter wrong edittext focus

Tags: android

In my android application i have an activity with a view pager, the last one has a fragment pager adapter as adapter with exactly 4 fragments.

Three of the four fragment have edit text on their layout, the problem is that when i'm in the last fragment then touching the screen lead to put focus on the first fragment's edit text !

what is the issue please ?

Comment: hello can you try         mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); and tell me what happens

Comment: Nothing new my friend..

Comment: Can you post the code